# How to get DecimalFormat to display ASCII strings instead of special symbols?

Tags: java, string, formatting, numbers

While playing around with `double` string formatting, I noticed that, at least on my locale, the strings produced by a default [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) object are different than the ones generated by [`Double.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28%29) when it comes to special cases like `Infinity` and `NaN`. E.g. from this snippet:

```
for (double i : new double[]{ 1/0.0, -1/0.0, 0/0.0 }) {
    System.out.println(Double.toString(i));
    System.out.println(new DecimalFormat().format(i));
}
```

I get this output:

```
Infinity
∞
-Infinity
-∞
NaN
�
```

This not only causes issues with existing code that is watching out for `NaN` and `Infinity`, but the last symbol is unreadable with the fonts on my development system. As far as I can tell by checking its numeric value, that last symbol is the `U+FFFD` Unicode replacement character, which probably means that it has not actually been set to something meaningful.

Since for some of my applications I prefer the 7-bit ASCII representations (*"Be liberal in what you accept, be conservative in what you produce"*), is there some way to force the strings produced by `DecimalFormat` to match those produced by `Double.toString()`?

One way might be to provide a [`DecimalFormatSymbols`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) of my own, but it seems that I'd have to set all related fields myself, which sounds somewhat fragile. Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to change it using DecimalFormatSymbols class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

you can get the DecimalFormatSymbols object from your DecimalFormat and modify it. see the below code snippet. So you don't need to set all fields.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = df.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setNaN("NaN");
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer, since this seems to be the actual answer, disappointing as it is...

Comment: `getDecimalFormatSymbols` returns a copy of the internal object, so modifying it will not modify the symbols of the existing DecimalFormat object. You will need to call `setDecimalFormatSymbols` or pass a DecimalFormatSymbols object in the DecimalFormat constructor.

Comment: As @Mikkel noted, you are missing an additional instruction: `df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);`

Comment: @jcfrei, modified the answer. Thanks